# How to get coresponding hover and active color details from Metronic Color Library?

Tags: metronic

In Metronic theme, we have color library http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/ui_colors.html.

From that, how do I get the colors for other states like hover, active, disable, focus. Could you please provide any suggestions?

Comment: To get color, you can use browser inspector to read the css definition (e.g. you may need to check the hover option to view hover state)

Comment: I guess you want to set the color for the state hover for example - well the color library is about css class to use to make the UI element turned into that color scheme i.e. colors for that scheme including normal color, hover color etc. Still NOT see how we use a css class specialized for hover state only.